# Commodore 64 programmers, How To Use ReSid In C++ Game?

Tags: audio, emulation, c64

Would it be possible to use the ReSID emulation source code in a game I'm making? I want a video game sound engine like the good old days. Not wavs/mp3s. Any thoughts? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSID

Comment: Sure, why not?  It's GPL, but if the licensing is okay with you, it seems it is a library that you can drop in and use.

Comment: Cool :) Well, I should have been more clear. If it is even technically possible. I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing it. No idea where to start.

Comment: Have a look at the source code for something else that uses ReSID, like "SIDPlayer" (http://sidplayer.cebix.net/). Try writing your own code that does something similar, opening a SID file and playing it. You can then move that function into a thread in your game. However, unless you intend to do some funky dynamic changes to the music based on what happens in the game, there is no practical reason why you would use a SID emulator within your game, instead of just using a recording of a SID emulator (MP3/WAV).

Comment: @jjokin, That last part certainly bursts my bubble :/ The whole reason I want synthesis is /for/ the dynamics. Sampling the SID is ok, but it's not my goal. I really want real-time synthesis. Looks like I've got my work cut out for me. Thanks so much for the tip, though. :)

Comment: You can still have dynamic music using MP3s. Any volume manipulation, cross fading, or layering of music can be done using a software mixer as part of your game engine. If you really wanted to get fancy you could record each instrument on a separate track, mix the tracks in realtime in your game, and apply different effects to individual tracks rather than the whole music.

Comment: Well that's interesting. I didn't know that. Well, I'm still determined to get some synthesis. 8 voices is plenty. Just something to play with in game.